# Python: Select Only Parts of an input?

Tags: python, select, random, input

Sorry...I'm kind of a programming noob.  I was looking at some problem sets online and I found [THIS ONE](http://openbookproject.net/pybiblio/practice/wilson/powerball.php).  I wrote this much:

```
import random

powerball=random.randint(1,42)

a=random.randint(1,53)
b=random.randint(1,53)
c=random.randint(1,53)
d=random.randint(1,53)
e=random.randint(1,53)

(f,g,h,i,j)=x=input("Your 5 Chosen Numbers:")
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make the program print something like "Please enter 5 numbers separated by only a comma" if more or less than five are entered.  Also how would I do that if I wanted it to display a different message every other time they made that mistake?

Comment: Why Python tutorial are you using?

Comment: On the Tim Wilson's^page, there is : "The first 5 numbers are drawn from a drum containing 53 balls and the 6th is drawn from a drum containing 42 balls. The chances of doing this are 1 in 120,526,770." But 53*52*51*50*49*42 makes 14463212400 ; What am I understanding wrong ?

Comment: @eyquem: It doesn't matter which order you draw the first 5 numbers. C(53, 5) * 42 = 120526770.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill How dumb I am. 14463212400 needs to be divided by 5! Thank you. So it confirms me that it's 53*52*51*50*49, each ball is definitely extracted from the  drum. That's why Tim Wilson writes "by utilizing the choice function in Python's random module. 
"; The use of randint() by jacKeown is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
input_is_valid = False
while not input_is_valid:
    comma_separated_numbers = raw_input("Please enter a list of 5 numbers,separated by commas: ")
    numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in comma_separated_numbers.split(",")]
    if len(numbers) != 5:
        print "Please enter exactly 5 numbers"
    else:
        input_is_valid = True
```

Comment: Hmm...I might be able to understand that...but I don't get this line...

 numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in comma_separated_numbers.split(",")]

Comment: That code is a list comprehension, which applies an expression to each element in an iterable and puts the results in a list (it's a kind of loop, you could say). In this case, it is applying `int(x.strip())` to every `x` in `comma_separated_numbers.split(',')`, which takes the input (of comma-separated numbers) and splits it by commas; then, each element is converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```
import random
import sys

powerball=random.randint(1,42)

a=random.randint(1,53)
b=random.randint(1,53)
c=random.randint(1,53)
d=random.randint(1,53)
e=random.randint(1,53)


bla = ["\nPlease enter 5 numbers separated by only a comma : ",
       "\nPlease, I need 5 numbers separated by only a comma : ",
       "\nPLEASE, 5 numbers exactly : ",
       "\nOh gasp ! I said 5 numbers, no more nor less : ",
       "\n! By jove, do you know what 5 is ? : ",
       "\n==> I warn you, I am on the point to go off : "]

i = 0
while i<len(bla):

    x = raw_input(warn + bla[i])

    try:
        x = map(int, x.split(','))
        if len(x)==5:
            break
        i += 1

    except:
        print "\nTake care to type nothing else than numbers separated by only one comma.",

else:
    sys.exit("You wanted it; I go out to drink a beer : ")

(f,g,h,i,j)=x
print f,g,h,j,i
```

.

Some explanation:

.

for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]

A **break** statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the else clause’s suite. A continue statement executed in the first suite skips the rest of the suite and continues with the next item, or with the else clause if there was no next item.

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-801

.

.

**x = map(int, x.split(','))**
means that the function **int()** is applied to each element of the iterable which is the second argument.
Here the iterable is the list **x.split(',')**
Hence, **x** is a list of 5 integers
In Python 3, there is no more **raw_input()** , it has been replaced by **input()** that receives characters, as **raw_input()** in Python 2.

.

.

Comment: @Mattia Gobbi Thank you. It's kind for you to have upvoted my answer ! warf :o)

Comment: hey man, why be sarcastic! :-) I found it witty, but your code although rich in idioms is not the best example of python code here (not that mine is), so I wasn't sure it would be right to upvote. Also it was 2 a.m. and I went to bed immediately after posting, go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link I'd say:

```
import random

while True:
    sets = input('how many sets? ')
    if type(sets) == int:
        break
    else:
        pass

for i in range(sets):
    ri = random.randint
    powerball = ri(1,42)
    other_numbers = sorted(ri(1,53) for i in range(5))
    print 'your numbers:','\t',other_numbers,'\t','powerball:','\t',powerball
```

It seems that's more or less what he asks from you.
If I'm correct, you want the user to submit his series so to see if its one of the sets extracted (amirite?)

then it could be fine to do:

```
import random

while True:
    sets = input('how many sets? ')
    if type(sets) == int:
        break
    else:
        pass

while True:
    myset = raw_input('your 5 numbers:').split()
    if len(myset) != 5:
        print "just five numbers separated ny a space character!"
    else:
        myset = sorted(int(i) for i in myset)
        break


for i in range(sets):
    ri = random.randint
    powerball = ri(1,42)
    numbers = sorted(ri(1,53) for i in range(5))
    print 'numbers:','\t',numbers,'\t','powerball:','\t',powerball
    if numbers == myset:
        print "you won!" ##or whatever the game is about
    else:
        print "ahah you loser"
```

EDIT: beware this doesn't check on random generated numbers. So it happens one number can appear more than once in the same sequence. To practice you may try avoiding this behavior, doing so with a slow pace learning some python in the way it could be:

1. make a set out of a copy of the list "numbers" -- use set()
2. if its length is less than 5, generate another number
3. check if the new number is in the list
4. if it is, then append it to the list. if its not unique yet, GOTO point 1 :-)
5. sort the whole thing again
6. there you go

happy reading the docs!

Comment: "So it happens one number can appear more than once in the same sequence. " Yes. That's why Tim Wilson wrote "by utilizing the choice function in Python's random module." because it's easy to apply choice() on a list range(1,54) in which the choosen number will be deleted before the next instruction choice() is applied.

Comment: @eyquem Yes, I noticed that. Sticked with randint because the thread opener used that, I didnt even think about other functions in the module.